# Connections between two types of convergence of random variable

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

> Let $\{\xi_n\}_{n\geq1}:(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})\to(\mathbb{R^1},\text{Bor})$ be a sequence of random variable. What are the connections between the following two types of convergence as $n\to\infty$?
>
> 1) $\xi_n\to\xi$ almost surely
>
> 2) $\xi_n\to\xi$ in the p-th mean, i.e. $\sum_{n\geq 1}E(|\xi_n-\xi|^p)<\infty$

According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables), convergence in p-th order mean implies convergence in probability, and convergence in probability implies there exists a sub-sequence which almost surely converges. Are there any other connections?

Edit: I realize that the second convergence is not convergence in the mean, so please ignore the above paragraph. What are the connections between just these two types of convergence?

Comment: shouldn't the $p$-th mean convergence be with a limit, and not a sum?

Comment: Well, you have Scheffé lemma that says that if $\xi_n\to \xi$ a.s. and $\mathbb E[\xi_n^p]\to \mathbb E[\xi^p]$, then $\xi_n\to \xi$ in $L^p$.

Comment: The Wikipedia article is very comprehensive. Which of the statements do you not understand?

Comment: Your convergence statement (2) is not what the cited wikipedia article calls convergence in p-th order mean.

Comment: @kimchilover Yes, you are right. Thank you for pointing it out.